# Formula to calculate optimal cell width and height of fishnet in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vector-grid

I am trying to create a fishnet-layer in ArcGIS over my data and the program is asking me for the cell size. Now I know I can just type any data in there but I was told there is a mathematical formula to calculate the optimal cell size based on the area that I would like to cover.

I have tried to find it on Google but with no success so far, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

After some more research I have found the answer

[image: Formula to determine optimal cell size]

A = Area of the study area
n = The number of points (samples, events, ...)

Comment: *Any* formula of this type is a rule of thumb and must have a basis in some objective.  What is the basis for this one?  (One guess is that it merely produces approximately the intended number of points -- but the OP doesn't even indicate that this value is known.)